# Chrome Remote Debug Can Not Discover Any USB Devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

My Huawei Ascend Phone has:

- Android 4.0.4
- Kernel version: 3.0.2
- USB Debugging – Settings > Developer options > Check “USB debugging”
- USB Web debugging – Chrome > Settings > Developer tools > Check “Enable USB Web debugging”

My Laptop computer has:

- Windows 7
- Chrome 35
- Install the official ADB Plugin Chrome Extension
- Click on the Android icon on Chrome menu and select “View inspection targets” or go straight to chrome://inspect.

I also tried following steps:
 - use SDK Manager to install Chrome USB driver
 - download and install Chrome Canary
 - install Koushik Dutta's Universal ADB (Android Debug Bridge) Driver for Windows: https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

But I still cannot Discover any USB Devices, Why?

Answer (score 2):

For people who had the same problem.

Install Android SDK tool & HiSuite. I download some driver for specific Huawei mobile, but don't work. The HiSuite install some other driver and chrome://inspect found the device.

Comment: This, along with using Chrome Beta on Android instead of the pre-installed version worked.